# PHP validating command line argv array for a set of command options

Tags: php, command-line

I am doing command line script with php and trying to develop validate the set of commands to see if they were there, but i am not going anyware with the following code, i dont know why it alwasy goes to the help().. even if i have the argv options like

```
sh#php geninvoices.php --type=generate --w --bill_day=7


$commands=array('--type','--bill_day','--save');
if(!in_array($commands, $argv)){
    print_r($argv);
    help();
}
```

any help ?

Comment: Do you have anything in `var_dump($argv);` (before `if`)? And look how they are represented there. Also `This variable is not available when register_argc_argv is disabled.`

Comment: it gets arguments correctly i.e Array
(
    [0] => generate.php
    [1] => --type=generate
    [2] => --write
    [3] => --bill_day=7
)

Comment: Ok, what do you want to get in the end? To see if all of arguments are present or ... ? As you can see, `bill_day=7` and it will be never found by `in_array`. The same is for `--type=generate`. The solution is to loop through the `$argv`, break each by `=` and search in array by the part before the `=`

Answer (score 0):

Just to show the idea

```
$argv = array('generate.php', '--type=generate', '--write', '--bill_day=7');
$args = array();
foreach($argv as $i => $str)
{
    if ($i == 0) continue;
    list($arg, $value) = explode('=', $str, 2);
    $args[ltrim($arg, '-')] = $value;
}

var_dump($args);
```

And now you have arguments with values and you can do whatever you want.

```
array(3) {
  ["type"]=>
  string(8) "generate"
  ["write"]=>
  NULL
  ["bill_day"]=>
  string(1) "7"
}
```